# Defining input text as a number input in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, numbers

So, when I'm building an application in Flash and Actionscript 3.0 I create a sharedobject.data and I have an input field, the sharedobject is equal to the input field.But it's only restricted to numbers, but when the input is put in the number is thought to be text.. rather than an actual number (eg. "1" instead of just 1) is there anyway that I can make an input field into something like a number field?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var variable:Number;
variable= Number(input_txt.text);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you think the OP should do so?

Comment: My understanding is that the text field is always received as a string, so we need to convert the information gathered to a number. You could also restrict the text box to only accept numbers: 

`input_txt.restrict = "0-9.";`

Comment: Yes, I always restrict, but it still defines as a "9" rather than a 9.

Comment: @user1666767 to convert a string to a number just use what @Kieran said: `var myNumber = Number(string);`

Comment: Ok so restrictng is one step but then you still need to convert it to a Number